# Why static_assert in template gives me different result with equivalent expressions?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, static-assert

I've noticed strange behavior of `static_assert`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, unsigned int D> struct Vec
{
    static_assert(D && 0, "Invalid dimension for vector!");
};

template <typename T> struct Vec<T, 1>             {union {T x, r;};};
template <typename T> struct Vec<T, 2> : Vec<T, 1> {union {T y, g;};};
template <typename T> struct Vec<T, 3> : Vec<T, 2> {union {T z, b;};};
template <typename T> struct Vec<T, 4> : Vec<T, 3> {union {T w, a;};};

int main()
{
    Vec<float, 3> v;
    v.x = 1;
    v.y = 2;
    v.z = 3;

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine: http://ideone.com/wHbJYP . I would expect

```
static_assert(0, "Invalid dimension for vector!");
```

to give me same result, but it causes static assertion failure: http://ideone.com/UEu9Kv .
Is gcc correct in both cases? If so, why? Or is it a gcc bug? Then, in which case gcc is correct?

Comment: Why would you expect different behavior?

Comment: This is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, so GCC is correct in both cases.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I would expect *same* behavior, but it's different!

Comment: @T.C. Why it's ill-formed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

§14.6 [temp.res]/p8:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that
>   template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no
>   diagnostic required.

In both cases no valid specialization can be generated for the primary template due to the `static_assert` (`D && 0` is never true no matter the value of `D`). Since no diagnostic is required, the compiler is free to diagnose one (when you use `0`) but not the other (when you use `D && 0`).

Workaround:

```
template <unsigned int D> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, unsigned int D> struct Vec
{
    static_assert(always_false<D>::value, "Invalid dimension for vector!");
};
```

The compiler can no longer reject this at definition time, as there might be an explicit specialization of `always_false` whose `value` member is `true`.

Comment: The weird part is that by that explanation the first static assert (D && 0) should also cause the template to be ill formed but that one compiles fine.  I'm curious, too, as to what's going on here.

Comment: @mbgda "ill-formed" only requires the compiler to produce a diagnostic message (which can be an error or a warning). "no diagnostic required" means that the compiler is allowed to compile the code even without producing a diagnostic.

Comment: @TC I thought you said no diagnostic is required only if the template is not instantiated - did I read it incorrectly?

Comment: @mbgda The OP didn't instantiate the primary template. The code instantiated only the partial specializations.

Comment: @T.C. Looks like your explanation is not fully correct. `std::is_void<int>::value` condition doesn't work, but `std::is_void<T>::value` is ok. It's strange, because I can redefine them both to be `1`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `std::is_void<int>::value` doesn't work because nothing in there is dependent on a template parameter, so everything is looked up and evaluated at template definition time. Also, specializing a standard library type trait (except `std::common_type` for user-defined types) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @T.C. Ok, thanks. BTW, this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797) says that template specializations are allowed, that's why I assumed that I can do it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Most of them are allowed for user-defined types, but type traits are special.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is not 1,2,3,4 (for which specific specializations exist)  will go into the "master" definition, that have to assert for every value of D it will be called.

So you need *an expression that contains D* and that is *always false*, to cause the compiler to evaluate it *in dependency of D*

If you just use 0, it will be anymore dependent and the compiler will evaluate as it matches during parsing, causing the assertion to always take place. Even if it will not be the class you will instantiate.

Comment: Then compiler behavior then makes sense, but can you provide a corresponding reference to the standart?